# In werewolv.es, how does a Harpy's shroud interact with a second-place, balanced "no lynch"?

Tags: werewolv.es

Given a situation where there are the following votes:

1. Loki = 7 votes;
2. Hulk = 4 votes;
3. "No Lynch" = 4 votes.

If Loki has been shrouded by a Harpy, will there be a guaranteed "no lynch" situation (discounting other vote modifiers such as silenced players, puppets, etc)?

Is there any situation (again, discounting other "obvious" vote modifiers) where Hulk would be at risk of being lynched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "No Lynch" option follows the same majority & balance rules as it would if people were voting for a player instead (apart from the fact that no one dies). The only exception is that the "No Lynch" cannot be shrouded by a Harpy.

So assuming all votes are real and carry weight in the example given, this plays out the same way as the "No Lynch" votes being on another player (balance) and therefore, no risk for Hulk.